# getNext() Linked List

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I'm really new to Java and StackOverflow so please don't be mean. I would really appreciate some help. Thank you in advanced.

I feel like this is really easy and I've already tried this out a million different ways but it's not working.

I am trying to take in a text file and store it into a linked list and I'm trying to access the third node of this linked list. For some reason, I can access the first node, then I can use the getNext() command to go to the next node, but when I try to use getNext() to go the third node, it continues to return the second node. So it is not going to third node. 
Am I just missing some key concept? Also let me know if you need anymore information.

The text file that is being taken in is:
5 
A B C D E 
A B //This is the line that I want
B C
B D
C D
C E
D E

Here is part of my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    /**
     * Check whether the user types the command correctly
     */
    if (args.length != 1)
    {

        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        System.out.println(args.length);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String filename = args[0];
    Scanner input = new Scanner (new File(filename));

            LinkedList<String> linkedList= new LinkedList<String>();

            while(input.hasNext())
    {
        linkedList.addToRear(input.nextLine());
    }

            LinearNode<String> link= linkedList.firstLink;

            String temp = " ";
    link.getNext();
    temp = (String)link.getElement();
    String[] numofVerticesArray = temp.split(" ");
    int numOfVertices = Integer.parseInt(numofVerticesArray[0]);
    int lineNumber = 1;

    String [] arrayOfVertices; 
    LinearNode<String> secondLine = link;
    String temp2;


    for (int i=0; i <= lineNumber; i++)
    {
        secondLine = link.getNext();
    }
    lineNumber = 2;
    temp2 = (String)secondLine.getElement();
    arrayOfVertices = temp2.split(" ");

            int[][] adjMatrix = new int[numOfVertices][numOfVertices];

    LinearNode<String> edgeLine = link;
    String [] arrayOfEdge;
    int rowCount = 0;
    int columnCount = 0;
    String temp3;
    lineNumber = 2;

    for (int i=0; i <= lineNumber; i++)
    {
        edgeLine = link.getNext();
        System.out.print((String)edgeLine.getElement());
                    //When this is printed out, the second node's 
                    //content is printed out, not the third node
    }
    lineNumber++;
    temp3 = (String)edgeLine.getElement();
    arrayOfEdge = temp3.split(" ");
```

Comment: Overall I would suggest reviewing the concepts and trying to rewrite the program from scratch(it would be good practice for you). Also keep in mind that if you call `getNext` then make sure you store it somewhere and remember it. In your code whenever you call `getNext` you constantly keep on forgetting the `getNext` value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You keep on asking for the second element from the LinkedList.

```
edgeLine = link.getNext();
```

sets the value of second element of the LinkedList link into `edgeLine`, and then you loop and do the same, and then the same over and over and over again.

Try doing

```
edgeLine = edgeLine.getNext();
```

This will keep on moving.

Comment: I knew it was something simple!! Thank you soooooooo much!! I shall choose this as the answer in 6 minutes when it lets me! :)

Comment: @user3023346 No problem :) I am glad that I could be of help. I have actually failed my first midterm due to this question back in university. So now that is what I always check for. So go and ace that test/assignment :)

Answer (score 0):

The only assignment you make to the `link` variable is this: `link= linkedList.firstLink;`. You're never assigning anything else to it. So calling `link.getNext()` will always return the same node, namely the second one. `link` is not an iterator, thus you can't call `getNext()` and advance through the linked list.